# Examples of Countable groups in which order of every non identity element is 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$P(\mathbb{N})$ (Power Set of set of natural numbers) with symmetric difference is an example of an uncountable group in which every non identity element is of order 2. (One more example is countable direct product of $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$)

If $n=2^{k}$ where k is a non-negative integer then two examples of groups of order n in which every non identity elements are of order 2 are:

1. $P(S)$ with symmetric difference (where S is any set of cardinality k such that $n=2^{k}$)
2. Direct product of $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ n number of times.

My question is: If n is not a power of 2, are there examples of such groups? Further can anyone give me an example of countably infinite group with the above mentioned property?

Comment: A group in which ever element is of exponent 2 is necessarily abelian. All such groups are vector spaces over the field with $2$ elements. If you accept the axiom of choice, they all have the form of a direct sum of (possibly infinitely many) copies of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. By Cauchy's Theorem, if every element of a finite group has exponent 2, then the order of the group must be a power of $2$.

Comment: As for a countably infinite such group, $\bigoplus_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ will do.

Comment: Your examples $P(S)$ and ${({\Bbb Z}/2})^S$ appear to be isomorphic (whether $S$ is finite or not). So basically you have only one example.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, it appears that the direct product $\Pi_{\Bbb N} {\Bbb Z}/2$ meets the requirements but is not a direct sum. In particular it is uncountable. No?

Comment: @HewWolff It is isomorphic to a direct sum of $2^{\aleph_0}$ copies. Again, it's a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_2$. If you accept AC, then it has a basis and is *necessarily* isomorphic to a direct sum of as many copies as the cardinality of the basis.

Comment: Nice, thanks. I guess $\Pi_\kappa {\Bbb Z}/2 \simeq \bigoplus_{2^\kappa} {\Bbb Z}/2$ for any cardinal $\kappa$. And maybe also for primes other than $2$.